# Is nel -= nel/2 functionally equivalent to nel /= 2?

Tags: c, division, subtraction, size-t

I recently came across this chunk of code as part of the `bsearch` implementation from musl:

```
else if (sign < 0)
    nel /= 2;
else {
    base = try;
    nel -= nel/2;
}
```

`nel` is a `size_t`.

Is `nel -= nel/2` functionally equivalent to `nel /= 2`?

Comment: What happens if `nel` is odd?

Comment: @HongOoi Figured it out just as I asked. See my answer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've self-answered correctly, but *for this code in particular*, after

```
base = try;
```

the first `nel/2` items have been chopped off from further consideration. If you just did `nel /= 2` at this point, and `nel` was odd, you'd also chop off the last item from further consideration, potentially producing false negatives.

Note that the code you're looking at [was recently changed](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit?id=3d8322c7ad659210a4c8770ef455ca729ce7f395) to always chop off the item that was compared in the case of non-equality.

Answer (score 3):

No. If `nel` is odd, then the result will be one less in `nel /= 2` than in `nel -= nel/2`.

For example, take `3`:

- After `nel /= 2`, `nel` will be `1`.
- After `nel -= nel/2`, `nel` will be `2`.

Comment: And in general, the statement `nel -= nel/2;` does "divide by two, rounding up".

Comment: And in the case of binary search, you have to get the rounding just right, otherwise the algorithm has a nasty habit of getting into an infinite loop when (in this case) `base -- nel - 1`.

Comment: @aschepler In the general case where `nel` may be signed or unsigned, `nel -= nel/2;` does "divide by two, rounding away from zero".